# Only print a footnote of a acronym once per page in the footnotes

Tags: acronyms

I want the acronym package to only print a footnote, if its not already printed on that specific page. And give the \acf{XX} the same number in the text. The output should look like this:

```
Text
The USA¹ are country as well as the UAE², but the USA¹ are bigger.

___________________
1 United States of America, 2 United Arabic Emirates

Next page:

The UAE¹ are still a country.

___________________
1 United Arabic Emirates
```

But it looks like this:

```
Text
The USA¹ are country as well as the UAE², but the USA³ are bigger.

___________________
1 United States of America, 2 United Arabic Emirates, 3 United States of America

Next page:

The UAE¹ are still a country.

___________________
1 United Arabic Emirates
```

My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage[1]{footnote} 



\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[ECU]
\acro{USA}{United States of America}
\acro{UAE}{United Arabic Emirates}
%[...]
\end{acronym}
\newpage

\section{Text}
The \acf{USA} are a country as well as the \acf{UAE}, but the \acf{USA} are bigger.
\newpage
The \acf{USA} are still a country.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is actually rather complicated, because it requires to 1. store the footnote number for each acronym, 2. reset the stored numbers on each page, 3. generate the correct hyperref target for a re-used footnote number (which are continuously numbered, i.e., the MWE generates targets `Hfootnote.1` to `Hfootnote.4`), and 4. also take into account regular footnotes not produced by `acronym`. But maybe someone here wants to give it a shot :)

Comment: The reset on each page works kinda easy with the perpage package - It has a option set all counters back to one on each page. Maby someone see this as a challenge and show his/her LaTeX Skills.

Comment: The perpage package may help, but a list of (acronym,footnote number) combinations is not a counter, so you will need to do something extra for step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `fixfoot` can be used for footnotes with the same text that are repeatedly used.

Switching from the `acronym` package to `acro` we can

- modify `\DeclareAcronym` to also declare a new fixed footnote;
- define a new template for the first appearance which calls said fixed footnote.

Here is an example document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% for demonstration purposes only: make the page small!
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=.5\textwidth,
  paperheight=15\baselineskip,
  margin=5pt,
  bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage[1]{footnote}

\NewCommandCopy\DeclareAcroymCopy\DeclareAcronym
\RenewDocumentCommand\DeclareAcronym{m+m}{%
  \DeclareAcroymCopy{#1}{#2}%
  \expandafter\DeclareFixedFootnote\csname#1@fixed@foot\endcsname{\acrofield{#1}{long}}%
}

\NewAcroTemplate{fixfoot}{%
  \acrowrite{short}%
  \acroiffirstT{\csname\AcronymID @fixed@foot\endcsname}%
}

\acsetup{
  first-style=fixfoot,
  % subsequent-style=fixfoot
}

\DeclareAcronym{USA}{short=USA,long=United States of America}
\DeclareAcronym{UAE}{short=UAE,long=United Arabic Emirates}

\begin{document}

\section{Text}
The \acf{USA} are a country as well as the \acf{UAE}, but the \acf{USA} are bigger.
\newpage
The \acf{USA} are still a country.

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

---

Someone more familiar with the `acronym` package can now maybe suggest a solution with it as well.

Comment: I tried the code with TeX Live 2021 and v3.6 of `acro.sty` (2022/01/04) but I get an error `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\use_iv:nnnn #1#2#3#4->
                       #4
l.23 ...}{short=USA,long=United States of America}`. Also there is no `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` but adding it does not make a difference. Does it work for you? (it might be that the kernel I used is too old (July 2021) but in that case it is a warning for other people that a very recent version is required)

Comment: @Marijn I have an up to date TL21 with v3.6 of `acro` and don't get any errors with the code

Comment: Thanks! I get an Error message with that code, that \NewCommandCopy is a undefinded control sequence (and all logically folowwing erorr messages, because of that). What do I need? I'm using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`, do I need an upgrade or a package?

Comment: @TrizZm4ster `\NewCommandCopy` has been added to the 2020-10-01 release of the LaTeX kernel. Your LaTeX is too old for the code. (BTW: don't update single packages, always update the disribution)

Comment: Got it! I will get a new Laptop tomorrow  anyway and just install a up to date version then :) Thanks for your help - LaTeX got a great community! :)